# Odoo server raises error Module CRM is not available on your system

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I am new to modules development. I want to add attributes and features to the existing crm_lead object. Working on 8.0 version.

I have created a new module with the scaffold feature. In the `__openerp__.py` manifest, I have added a dependency

```
# any module necessary for this one to work correctly
'depends': ['base','CRM'],
```

When trying to import the module, I get the error

```
 raise orm.except_orm(_('Error'), _("You try to install module '%s' that depends on module '%s'.\nBut the latter module is not available in your system.") % (module.name, dep.name,)) 
except_orm: (u'Error', u"You try to install module 'yvleads' that depends on module 'CRM'.\nBut the latter module is not available in your system.")
```

Here is the skeletton of the class. I have tried various import (from openerp, from CRM, import crm, import crm_lead) without much success.

```
class yvleads(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.crm_lead'
    _name = 'yvleads.yvleads'
    name = fields.Char()
    _column = { 'Last_Action': fields.Char('Last_Action', size=240, required=False) }
```

Any hint here or link to a good practise document or code example to override or add info to existing standard modules?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to put the name of the module as a package hence CRM goes in lower case:

```
'depends': ['base', 'crm'],
```

You can actually see it in other default addons modules like `crm_claim/__openerp__.py` that adds some functionality to the standard `crm` module.

For the class code itself, the `_inherit` attribute needs to refer to the correct mode name, ie the `_name` attribute of the `crm_lead` model. Here is the corrected class code

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
from openerp.addons.crm import crm_lead

class yvleads(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'
    _name = 'yvleads.yvleads'
    name = fields.Char()
    _column = { 'Last_Action': fields.Char('Last_Action', size=240, required=False) }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. I add as an edit to your question the correction for the class code.